# I am not able to retrive my data from api showing error " Cannot read properties of undefined " ,sometime i recieve data and most of the time i don't

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios, map-function

**useFetch.js**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        setData(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);
```

**PropertyList.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";
import "./propertyList.css";

function PropertyList() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/hotels/countByType"
  );

  console.log(data);

  const images = [
    "https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/1c/d3/b2/4f/exterior-view.jpg",
    "https://www.phillyaptrentals.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/apartment-building-what-makes-good-apartment-building-scaled.jpg",
    "https://dynamic-media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/1a/01/04/c9/manduna-resort.jpg?w=900&h=-1&s=1",
    "https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/585562bcbe659442d503893f/c3b765c0-45e3-46b3-9ff9-b4101fb30674/01.+Exotik+Villas+Bali+-+Aloui.jpg",
    "https://vancouverisland.travel/app/uploads/2021/04/wood-cabin-on-vancouver-island_BenGiesbrecht.jpg",
  ];

  return (
    <div className="pList">
      {loading ? (
        "Loading.."
      ) : (
        <>
          {data &&
            images.map((img, i) => (
              <div className="pListItem" key={i}>
                <img src={img} alt="" className="pListImg" />
                <div className="pListTitles">
                  <h1>{data[i].type}</h1>
                  <h2>
                    {data[i].count} {data[i].type}
                  </h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default PropertyList;
```

I think this may be because of fetching API into the res variable after PropertyList.jsx page calls the data state into the map function

**output of API : **
*[
{
"type": "hotel",
"count": 6
},
{
"type": "apartments",
"count": 0
},
{
"type": "resort",
"count": 0
},
{
"type": "villas",
"count": 0
},
{
"type": "cabins",
"count": 0
}
]*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what's the reason behind this error?

res.data, data key is missing in API response, so in this case you need to add conditions

The conditions is -

const res = await axios.get(url);
setData(res.data);

S/B

const res = await axios.get(url);

const data = (res.data !== undefined) ? res.data : [];

setData(data);

Comment: still showing the same error :(

Comment: @VarunNayak
add if condition (data.length > 0) before {data && images.map((img, i) => ()} And also start loop with data, not images.